# does update command to mongodb database from python returns result of query(e.g. boolean or integer)

Tags: python, mongodb, return-type, updatecommand

I'm very new to Python. In my script I have written code to update MongoDB database.

```
def mongoInsert(userData, collection):
    mconn = Connection(MONGODB_HOST,MONGODB_PORT)
    mdb = mconn[MONGODB_DBNAME]
    col = mdb[collection]

    #The below codeis used to upsert the data in MongoDB.
    for user in userData:
        print user
        col.update({'id': user[0]}, {'$set':user}, True)
return
```

where userData is a list,

```
 userData = []
```

When I run the command **python script_name.py** using putty; the script runs without any error or exception. But when I see **try** to see the data in MongoDB, there is no data added in databse(I'm not sure, may be data has been added, but as I'm new here, I'm not able to see it). So I'm thinking now if there is any way to get the rows updated in database after the update command(any return type of update command e.g. boolean or integer), I will use it like

```
success = col.update({'id': user[0]}, {'$set':user}, True)
print success
```

but it always prints None value of success. So is there any way to check data is added or not, modifying the above code.

Comment: this update command doesn't work. It runs without generating error and exception but it doesn't update the records, so now I'm posting another question to get the correct update command, whose link I will put here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that with the line

```
col.update({'id': user[0]}, {'$set': user}, True)
```

where user[0] is a whole document of user collection, you are trying to update document where id is a whole document. You should write smth like:

```
col.update({'_id': user[0]['_id']}, {'$set': user}, True)
```

Moreover i don't understand what are you trying to do with the part  `{'$set': user}`. Read [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set) and [this](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.1.1/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update#pymongo.collection.Collection.update).

To check that your query was ok you should pass the keyword argument `safe=True` to the update method:

```
success = col.update({'id': user[0]}, {'$set': user}, True, safe=True)
print success
```

Sorry if i did not understand your problem correctly.

Comment: yes and no. Yes, because I found out a way to check whether update command successfully completed or not and no because my problem is now changed, the above update command doesn't work. So now I'm posting another question to get the correct update command.